# Looping through dates in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the below XML.

```
<Timesheet>
   <StartDate>2013-06-12T00:00:00</StartDate>
   <EndDate>2013-06-18T00:00:00</EndDate>
   <Details>
      <TimesheetDetail>
         <BusinessDate>2013-06-12T00:00:00</BusinessDate>
         <Site>
            <a:Id>0201</a:Id>
         </Site>
         <TotalDuration>180</TotalDuration>
         <WorkType>
            <a:Category>
               <b:_displayName>Work</b:_displayName>
               <b:_value>3</b:_value>
            </a:Category>
            <a:Code>Mgmnt</a:Code>
            <a:Description>Management</a:Description>
         </WorkType>
      </TimesheetDetail>
      <TimesheetDetail>
         <BusinessDate>2013-06-13T00:00:00</BusinessDate>
         <Site>
            <a:Id>0202</a:Id>
         </Site>
         <TotalDuration>240</TotalDuration>
         <WorkType>
            <a:Category>
               <b:_displayName>Time Off</b:_displayName>
               <b:_value>3</b:_value>
            </a:Category>
            <a:Code>Bereavement</a:Code>
            <a:Description>Bereavement Leave</a:Description>
         </WorkType>
      </TimesheetDetail>
   </Details>
   <Employee>
      <a:EmpUserId>314Test2</a:EmpUserId>
      <a:FirstName>314Test2</a:FirstName>
   </Employee>
</Timesheet>
```

I need to write an XSLT which would generate a table which would have one column for 
Site : Value would be from Site attribute in each Timesheetdetail and 
A column for each day in between the StartDate and EndDate.
The TotalDuration value needs to go as the value for the above created columns matching the BusinessDate. If there are multiple TimesheetDetails, extra rows would be created.

The problem I'm facing is - How to loop through the StartDate and EndDate and generate columns dynamically for each date in XSLT? I would also need to display the "Day" for that date. Can we get that in XSLT?

Comment: the element `<a:id>`, can be a problem in xslt. if you can not escape in xslt.

Comment: The XML is getting generated using DataContractSerializer. Any idea how to avoid getting that <a:> thing?

Comment: escape witch <a\:id>.

Comment: Didn't get that Antonio.. Any more details?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, although I have not tried, the way to show **sites** is this:

```
<xsl:aply-template select="Timesheet/details"/>
```

this makes a **loop** all that is within **TimesheetDetail**.

```
<xsl:template match="TimesheetDetail">
  <xsl:value-of select="Site/." />
</xsl:template>
```